# Why should POST data be nested?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am using Rails as an API server, and I wonder why the data being sent to the server needs to be nested. This seems to be the preferred way of defining params:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :password, :username, :email)
end
```

And this would be the corresponding JSON sent to the create route:

```
{
    "user": {
        "username": "lorem",
        "first_name": "ipsum",
        "last_name": "dolor",
        "password": "sit",
        "email": "amet"
    }
}
```

Why is this the preferred way of posting data? Why could not the JSON be:

```
{
    "username": "lorem",
    "first_name": "ipsum",
    "last_name": "dolor",
    "password": "sit",
    "email": "amet"
}
```

Comment: No experience with RoR here, but to me this looks like it's due to you actually requiring a parameter `user` that contains the other fields?

Comment: Yes it is! But this how rails scaffolds the controller to begin with. I understand that there should be some reason to do this in the auto generated code and I like to know what the reason is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These aren't the only parameters that are sent while creating a resource for you, others are:

1. `utf8` with value `✓`
2. `authenticity_token` with a random string
3. `commit` with value either `Save` or `Update`

So the logic is pretty obvious: Rails groups all the user-belonging-parameters inside `user` key, and thus, it's easier to read, easier to interpret by the code, and easier to whitelist the related parameters.

Not only this, sometimes you will try to create multiple resources through one request, like a user has many books, so you would like to create a user, and at the same time, books - something called [Nested Resources](http://railscasts.com/episodes/139-nested-resources), and in that case, it will be like this:

```
{
  "user": 
  {
    "username": "john_don",
    "books":
    {
      "0":
      {
        "author_id": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I hope you get the idea.